# How to avoid data scaling while reading a wav file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wav

I have a 16-bit wav file which has floating point data whose range exceeds [-1 to +1], which I'm trying to read in MATLAB 2010b. 'Wavread', by default, scales the data to [-1 to +1], while using the 'native' option scales the data to integer values in the [-2^15 to 2^15] range. I want to avoid either and just read in the original data, as is, in single/double format. How do I do this? Does 'audioread' in newer MATLAB versions do anything different? 
Many thanks!

Comment: `audioread` still scales any audio data that is floating point to the range of `[-1,1]`.  If you want to access the data unscaled, you may need to parse through and read the data from the file yourself.  Consult this website here: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html - This is describing the full spec of the WAV standard.

Comment: Your wav file is floating point data?  Most wav files are integers.  How did you create/obtain such a file?  If you used wavwrite, for example, I'm pretty sure that your file will be ints.  Are you sure that your file contains floating point values?

Comment: @chipaudette - `wav` files can be floating point.  Check the WAV standard in the link I referenced to the OP above.  Also, MATLAB is cognizant of the data type.  It checks a flag within the header and performs the necessary scaling respecting that data type.  If the file was integer, then the data after it's read in with `audioread / wavread` will also be integer.

Comment: My wavfile was generated using this software called LMS Test.Xpress. It offers me the option to export measured data, like noise, vibration, pressure, force, etc as multi-channel wav files. This is how I have floating point data outside the [-1, +1] range.

Comment: @rayryeng - So is there no way MATLAB will be able to provide me the necessary output directly (with any available function)? Of course I can find out what my max/min amplitude is and use that to scale back the MATLAB read data. But I'm trying to build an automated process wherein the assumption is that the user won't open each individual file to know what the max/min amplitude is.

Comment: @chaitanyabhat - None.  You can't avoid this scaling in MATLAB if you use `audioread / wavread`.  You can reverse the scaling if you know the dynamic range of your data before reading it in as you said, but there isn't a way to automate this process unless you parse the data manually.

Comment: Maybe the scaling information is contained in the `opts` output of `wavread`? If so you can use it to reverse the scaling. Also, did you try to set the `fmt` parameter to `native`?

Comment: @A.Donda I checked and opts does not have the info I need. And yes, I have tried using the native option, and it scales the data to integer data depending on the bit rate. So my original data is still not being read.